# Looking for general advice, how are websites that have dynamic and interactive graphs/tables web-scraped in python?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to understand how to extract data that is dynamic and interactive like the following website: https://www.eurocontrol.int/Economics/DailyTrafficVariation-States.html

I have been searching the internet for hours, haven't been able to find a solution to how this is done. If anyone knows, please can you explain this? Not looking for code hand-outs, just need some advice on how this process is done. Trying to help someone automate a task for them and it requires this type of web-scraping.

Thank you!

Comment: Using a tool that is able to parse javascript - selenium or requests-html, for example

Comment: stackoverflow isn't an advice website, so your question is off-topic.